# Is it a good alternative of nested if-statement in PHP?

Tags: php, if-statement

For this use case, executing one function depends on successful executing another function which returning value or null as following.

```
$user = $userModel->createUser();

if ($user) {
    // I skip how $user is being used here.
    $order = $orderModel->createOrder();

    if ($order) {
        // I skip how $order is being used here.
        $invoice = $invoiceModel->createInvoice();

        if ($invoice) {
            // I skip how $invoice is being used here.
            $payment = $paymentModel->createPayment();

            if ($payment) {
                // I skip how $payment is being used here.
                $shipping = $shippingModel->createShipping();

                if ($shipping) {
                    $this->notifyCustomer();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I do understand that writing many nested if-statements is not a good practice. Is the following code snippet a better alternative?

```
$user = $userModel->createUser();
$order = null;

if ($user) {
    // I skip how $user is being used here.
    $order = $orderModel->createOrder();
}

$invoice = null;

if ($order) {
    // I skip how $order is being used here.
    $invoice = $invoiceModel->createInvoice();    
}

$payment = null;

if ($invoice) {
    // I skip how $invoice is being used here.
    $payment = $paymentModel->createPayment();
}

$shipping = null;

if ($payment) {
    // I skip how $payment is being used here.
    $shipping = $shippingModel->createShipping();
}

if ($shipping) {
    $this->notifyCustomer();
}
```

Why I doubt about this solution is because several variables are declared for just to escape the nested if-statements.

Comment: The big question here is, what is `$this` in your examples?

Comment: Personally, I would invert the ifs and make them leave the function when anything is `null`.

Comment: Simply *fail* whenever one of the object creation steps failed. I.e. `if (!$user) return false;`. Or `if (!$user) throw new Exception();`. In fact, if you would use exceptions within your `createX()` functions judiciously, this problem would solve itself.

Comment: You can read this article about [Object Calisthenics](https://williamdurand.fr/2013/06/03/object-calisthenics/)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I have edited my question. Maybe it is now a little more clearly.  It is not specific about creating database records but executing functions in general.

Comment: @deceze if thowing exception in each createX() function, I just can call each method right after each other without if-statement. That is a good alternative.

Comment: @Jerodev that is also an alternative, but in my case, I think I should throw exception in each createX() function, and use one try-catch around all function calling, because I might have the rest of the code below the calling function that need to be executed as well, thus cannot leave the function if anything is null.

Comment: That's why I'm generally in favour of throwing exceptions than returning `false`. If your function is called `createX`, and it cannot fulfil that task for whatever reason, then arguably that's an *exceptional failure* and not a case to simply return a value.

Comment: That edit completely changed your code. Can't answer anymore because it has been marked as a duplicate. Anyway, given the new code, suppose you want to `createInvoice()` then I would simply supply the `$order` object as an argument. Like this: `$invoiceModel->createInvoice($order)`. That makes sense because the invoice model needs to know which order to make an invoice for. If `$order` is null then it cannot do it. The same is true for all other method calls in your example.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware if passing created object to another function, in that function we do need to use if-statement as well of check if the passed variable is null or not. This is also a good alternative. Thank!

Comment: @KIKOSoftware But that means we first need to call the function and then check if the code in the function can be executed or not. I feel like we call for someone to come to us and ask if he has an apple or not. If he does not have, he did come for nothing. Why don't we first check if we have something on him before calling him, thus every time he comes he will never come for nothing. What do you think?

Comment: I think you need to get working on real code and see where it leads you. This is all too theoretical. In practice I have never encountered all these nested/sequential if-statements, and yes, I have made systems that deal with orders/invoices/shipments/etc. When writing good code this issue just doesn't occur.